# How do i get an Image for the various MessageBoxImage(s) or MessageBoxIcon(s)

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, messagebox

How do i get an `System.Drawing.Image` for the various `System.Windows.MessageBoxImage`(s) and/or 
`System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon`(s)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

[SystemIcons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.systemicons) is what I was looking for:

```
SystemIcons.Warning.ToBitmap();
```

Answer (score 41):

You can also include SystemIcons in your XAML as follows:

Include a converter (see code below) as a Resource, and an Image control in your XAML.
This Image sample here shows the information icon.

```
     <Window.Resources>
        <Converters:SystemIconConverter x:Key="iconConverter"/>
     </Window.Resources>

     <Image Visibility="Visible"  
            Margin="10,10,0,1"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            MaxHeight="25"
            VerticalAlignment="Top"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource iconConverter}, ConverterParameter=Information}"/>
```

Here is the implementation for the converter:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Interop;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace Converters
{
   [ValueConversion(typeof(string), typeof(BitmapSource))]
   public class SystemIconConverter : IValueConverter
   {
      public object Convert(object value, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         Icon icon = (Icon)typeof(SystemIcons).GetProperty(parameter.ToString(), BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static).GetValue(null, null);
         BitmapSource bs = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(icon.Handle, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
         return bs;
      }

      public object ConvertBack(object value, Type type, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
      {
         throw new NotSupportedException();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This works great! However, I noticed that StackOverflow operates under the Creative Commons licence. Thus I technically can't use/adapt your code in my commercial application (which I don't want to be under the Creative Commons licence) without your permission. Are you willing to give me permission? I can still credit your work.

Comment: @skybluecodeflier, any code posted to StackOverflow is creative commons: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12527/do-i-have-to-worry-about-copyright-issues-for-code-posted-on-stack-overflow

Comment: @Zamboni Is there any particular reason your converter ignores the `value` and performs the conversion using only the `parameter`? That seems atypical of converters.

Answer (score 20):

As others have stated `SystemIcons` is the class that should contain those icons, but on Windows 8.1 (and possibly on earlier versions too) the icons present in the `SystemIcons` differ from the ones displayed on the `MessageBoxes` in the case of Asterisk, Information and Question. The icons on the dialog look much *flatter*. See - for example - the Question icon:

[image: Question icon]

The icon in the dialog is the native dialog icon, and the leftmost icon on the form in the background is the icon retrieved from the `SystemIcons` class.

For various methods and details on how to get the icon from the MessageBox see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24261849/1552016), but I include here a quick summary, just for the sake of completeness:

You should use the [`SHGetStockIconInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762205%28VS.85%29.aspx) function:

```
 SHSTOCKICONINFO sii = new SHSTOCKICONINFO();
 sii.cbSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SHSTOCKICONINFO));

 Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR(SHGetStockIconInfo(SHSTOCKICONID.SIID_INFO,
         SHGSI.SHGSI_ICON ,
         ref sii));
 pictureBox1.Image = Icon.FromHandle(sii.hIcon).ToBitmap();
```

Please [note](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762205%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> If this function returns an icon handle in the **hIcon** member of the
>   **SHSTOCKICONINFO** structure pointed to by psii, you are responsible for
>   freeing the icon with **DestroyIcon** when you no longer need it.

Of course for this to work you will have to define a few enums and structs:

```
public enum SHSTOCKICONID : uint
{
    //...
    SIID_INFO = 79,
    //...
}

[Flags]
public enum SHGSI : uint
{
    SHGSI_ICONLOCATION = 0,
    SHGSI_ICON = 0x000000100,
    SHGSI_SYSICONINDEX = 0x000004000,
    SHGSI_LINKOVERLAY = 0x000008000,
    SHGSI_SELECTED = 0x000010000,
    SHGSI_LARGEICON = 0x000000000,
    SHGSI_SMALLICON = 0x000000001,
    SHGSI_SHELLICONSIZE = 0x000000004
}

[StructLayoutAttribute(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public struct SHSTOCKICONINFO
{
    public UInt32 cbSize;
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public Int32 iSysIconIndex;
    public Int32 iIcon;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 260/*MAX_PATH*/)]
    public string szPath;
}

[DllImport("Shell32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern Int32 SHGetStockIconInfo(SHSTOCKICONID siid, SHGSI uFlags, ref SHSTOCKICONINFO psii);
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend the Icon Class:

```
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

    public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this Icon icon)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = icon.ToBitmap();
        IntPtr hBitmap = bitmap.GetHbitmap();

        ImageSource wpfBitmap = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(
            hBitmap,
            IntPtr.Zero,
            Int32Rect.Empty,
            BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

        if (!DeleteObject(hBitmap))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception();
        }

        return wpfBitmap;
    }
```

Extend the MessageBoxImage Enum:

```
    public static ImageSource ToImageSource(this MessageBoxImage enumValue)
    {
        switch (enumValue)
        {
            case MessageBoxImage.Error:
                return SystemIcons.Error.ToImageSource();
            case MessageBoxImage.Question:
                return SystemIcons.Question.ToImageSource();
            case MessageBoxImage.Warning:
                return SystemIcons.Warning.ToImageSource();
            case MessageBoxImage.Information:
                return SystemIcons.Information.ToImageSource();
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Profit:

*(Not gonna post the whole WPF Window code here, but "Icon" and "Image" are Properties of Type "ImageSource", linked to Image controls through Data Binding)*

```
    public ConfirmationWindow(Icon icon, MessageBoxImage image, string title, string content, bool defaultIsYes = true)
    {
        InitializeComponent();            

        Icon = icon.ToImageSource();
        Image = image.ToImageSource();
        Title = title;
        Content = content;
        DefaultIsYes = defaultIsYes;
    }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
MessageBox.Show(
  "Hello, world!",
  "My App",
  MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
```

As simple as that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but i actually want an instance of the bitmap used, not "how to show the message box". And welcome to stackoverflow